# I tried to get name from SharedPreferences method but when run code show null value in the console in flutter How to solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sharedpreference

In my code at the home page fetch user name from firestore database and that's display nicely in UI. I want pass that name to shared preference function and store there and use that name in another pages also.

At my previous question I have solved saving name to sharedpreference method but now I couldn't display .It's show null.

**Console Screenshot**:
[image]

code

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    fetchName();
    storeName();
    getStoreName();
  }

  Future getStoreName() async {
    getNameFromSharedPreferences();
    print("name $displayName");
  }

  void storeName() {
    String displayName = '${user?.displayName}';
    saveNameToSharedPreferences(displayName);
  }
```

[image]

**SharedPreferences code**

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

String? _displayName;

String? get displayName => _displayName;

Future saveNameToSharedPreferences(String displayName) async {
  final SharedPreferences sn = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  await sn.setString('displayName', displayName);
}

Future getNameFromSharedPreferences() async {
  final SharedPreferences sn = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  _displayName = sn.getString('displayName');
}
```

[image]

how to get name and display from SharedPreferences method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `getNameFromSharedPreferences()` is a `future` you need to `await` and then display the value of `name`

```
Future getStoreName() async {
    await getNameFromSharedPreferences(); // add await here
    print("name $displayName");
  }
```

And make sure that `name` is stored in the `sharedPreference` by logging it out